# SQL list employees manager's phone number and name if they dont have a manager

Tags: sql, oracle

This is from my homework, I was able to get number three easy enough but number four says to do the same as number three but also include those who do not have a manager. I cannot figure this one out, I tried case, iif, if then, etc I must be formatting it the wrong way but I cannot find anyhting helpful in my book. Please help.

1. From the employees table, list the `employee_id`, `last_name`, and `phone_number` of every employee, along with the last_name and phone number of his manager. Sort the rows by `employee_id`. (Hint:tables can be joined to themselves.Just give each table a different alias).

SQL:

```
  SELECT a.employee_id,
         a.last_name,
         a.phone_number,
         b.last_name AS manger_name,
         b.phone_number AS manger_phone
    FROM l_employees a,
         l_employees b
   WHERE a.manager_id = b.employee_id
ORDER BY a.employee_id
```

Comment: look up and read about `LEFT JOIN` operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick you're looking for is a left join:

```
SELECT    a.employee_id, a.last_name, a.phone_number, 
          b.last_name AS manger_name, b.phone_number AS manger_phone
FROM      l_employees a
LEFT JOIN l_employees b ON a.manager_id = b.employee_id
ORDER BY  a.employee_id
```

This can also be done with Oracle's implicit join syntax (notice the `(+)`):

```
SELECT   a.employee_id, a.last_name, a.phone_number,
         b.last_name AS manger_name, b.phone_number AS manger_phone
FROM     l_employees a, l_employees b
WHERE    a.manager_id = b.employee_id (+)
ORDER BY a.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little clarification to Mureinik's answer.  What's happening here is that normally with a join only rows from both tables where the relationship in the where clause is true are returned.  The outer join (left Join) or (+) tells it to return all the rows from the table on the left side, regardless of whether there is a match in the table on the right hand side, but if there is a match in the table on the right hand side, go ahead and fill in those columns too.  Outer joins like this are very powerful but there are a few things to look out for.

1. Make sure you really want everything from the table on the left side.  If you don't put in some other clauses in your where clause to limit what is considered by table "A".
2. The empty values (not in table "B" (managers)) in your case, are going to be NULL.  If you are using this in PLSQL or as a recordset being returned to a program somewhere, you might want to put some NVL statements around the potential NULL columns just to avoid errors.

Comment: I would upvote you if I had enough reputation. Thank you that helped a lot.